# how can I speed up ruby on rails tests on windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I've started learning to use Ruby on Rails running on Windows 7, and the time to run tests is painful I'm wondering if I can speed it up.
  Right now I am using the default test framework (inheriting from ActionController), with a SQLite database and the webrick web server.

While unit and functional tests report a runtime of less than 2 seconds, from the time I run the tests from the command-line to completion is actually 40 secounds.

A friend recommended I use guard.  That looks like it will help start the tests as soon as I save, but it seems like the real cost is starting up the webserver or database.  I wonder if it might be better to set up apache or mysql and use those locally instead.

Anyhow, what tips do people have for speeding up ruby on rails tests on windows?  I tried running the tests on Amazon EC2 linux micro instance (again with webrick and sqlite) and there was significant startup time (though I did not time it).

I tried "rake test --trace".  There was a significant pause:

- Immediately before the first line of output
- Between outputing "Execute environment" and "Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations"
- Between "Execute test:units" and "Run options:"

  The first pause seems worse.

Comment: You dont need to start any webserver to run units & functionals. try running `rake test --trace` and see if you can figure out where it's hanging up

Comment: Thanks olore, I ran the trace and noted where the pauses happen.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use [spork](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork) which now works in Windows. It runs on windows by pre-populating a pool of ready processes (referred to as the “magazine” strategy). The result is that webserver startup time is dramatically reduced.

If running rails on Windows is really the bottleneck then you can run a virtual machine using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and run an instance of Ubuntu and work on your rails projects in the VM.

Comment: FYI I emailed one of the old maintainers of the gem `spork-rails` and they told me to use `spring` instead.

Comment: @KaMok thanks but it seems `spring` doesn't support Windows. From the docs `Spring makes extensive use of Process.fork, so won't be able to provide a speed up on platforms which don't support forking (Windows, JRuby).`

Comment: Yeah I realized. I'm not using anything to speed up my tests at the moment and it's quite painful to do TDD. Been searching around this topic for months.

Comment: @KaMok I'd look into using a virtual machine or docker. I myself do rails work on a Mac which is great.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I actually had to work on my Windows 10 machine today and rails boots up extremely fast for Rails 5. I made a stackoverflow thread on it, because I don't quite understand it. I went from 17 seconds on Windows 7 to 5 seconds with my Windows 10. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748904/why-does-rails-5-on-windows-10-run-significantly-faster-than-windows-7